# Comunication Android App with WCF Rest Service

Tags: java, android, wcf, apache, rest

I'm  trying to communicate my Android App with a WCF REST service, but when I run the android app, always appears a message saying, unfortunately, android app has stopped.

Below is my call to the service , my app has one only activity that has a  Button when a click executes the event LogarOnserver, as you can see below. After the service return the response I take it and put in a TextView (_myPassWord).

```
package com.arduino.ligthautomation;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


 public class RegisterActivity extends Activity  {

EditText _myPassWord ;
EditText _myLogin;
private static final String URL_STRING =      "http://192.168.0.3:8080/lightautomationservice/1";

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //mostrando tela de login
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

     _myPassWord = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
     _myLogin = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editTextUsuario);




}

public void logarOnServer (View v) throws IOException
{
    try{

         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://192.168.0.3:8080/lightautomationservice/1");
         ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
         //you result will be String :
         String result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);

         _myLogin.setText(result);

           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
           }
}

}
```

Comment: where does this error come from? post the entire stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: you're doing a network request on the main(UI) thread. A big no no.

Look up [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)